# PuTTY network error when running Python scripts on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pi-3, android, putty

I run Python scripts on my Raspberry Pi from my Android device and it always works for 3 or 4 times, but when I do it more, PuTTY tells me the following:

```
Network error: Software caused connection abort
```

(During these 3-5 attempts, I watch PuTTY and enter basic commands in PuTTY to check if my laptop is still connected to the Pi)

How can I debug this? Is there a problem in my Python script on my Raspberry Pi, in the Android app or with some kind of network issue?